# Converting a forwarding lambda to a function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, function-pointers, generic-lambda

Here are two things that work. We can instantiate a forwarding function template to get a function pointer taking an lvalue:

```
template <class T>
void f(T &&) {}

void(*p)(int &) = f; // Cool!
```

We can also convert a non-capturing generic lambda taking an lvalue to a function pointer taking an lvalue:

```
auto l = [](auto &) { };

void (*lp)(int &) = l; // Still cool!
```

But apparently none of GCC and Clang will convert a forwarding generic lambda into a function pointer taking an lvalue:

```
auto l = [](auto &&) { };

void (*lp)(int &) = l; // Not cool!
```

GCC outputs:

```
<source>:9:21: error: invalid user-defined conversion from '<lambda(auto:1&&)>' to 'void (*)(int&)' [-fpermissive]
 void (*lp)(int &) = l;
                     ^
```

Clang outputs:

```
<source>:9:8: fatal error: no viable conversion from '(lambda at <source>:7:10)' to 'void (*)(int &)'
void (*lp)(int &) = l;
       ^            ~
<source>:7:10: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'type-parameter-0-0 &&' against 'int &'
auto l = [](auto &&) { };
         ^
```

This is all despite the fact that a member function pointer taking an lvalue *can* be obtained from the forwarding lambda:

```
auto lmp = &decltype(l)::operator()<int &>;

template <class...>
struct check;
check<decltype(lmp)> c;
```

... which outputs the type `void (<lambda(auto:1&&)>::*)(int&) const` as expected.

I thought that reference collapsing rules were inherent to any template instantiation, and expected this to work. Do both Clang and GCC have a bug, or is that not actually provided by the Standard?

Comment: The rules are different for generic lambdas. Starting point here: 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TL;DR: This is the specified behavior according to the standard. Template argument deduction has a special rule for deducing template arguments when taking the address of a function template, allowing forwarding references to work as expected. There is no such rule for conversion function templates.

<sup>Note: this looks like it's just an area for which nobody has written a proposal yet. If *someone* writes a proposal for this, it seems likely that this could be made to work in the future.</sup>

---

From [**[expr.prim.lambda]**](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#closure-7):

> ... . For a generic lambda with no lambda-capture, the closure type has a conversion function template to pointer to function. **The conversion function template has the same invented template parameter list, and the pointer to function has the same parameter types, as the function call operator template.** The return type of the pointer to function shall behave as if it were a decltype-specifier denoting the return type of the corresponding function call operator template specialization.

<sup>emphasis added</sup>

This states that the template arguments and function parameter types must be copied in a one-to-one manner:

```
// simplified version of the example in [expr.prim.lambda]/8
struct Closure {
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T&& t) const {
        /* ... */
    }

    template <typename T>
    static void lambda_call_operator_invoker(T&& t) {
        Closure()(std::forward<T>(t));
    }

    // Exactly copying the template parameter list and function parameter types.
    template <typename T>
    using fn_type = void(*)(T&&);
    // using fn_type = void(*)(T); // this compiles, as noted later

    template <typename T>
    operator fn_type<T>() const {
        return &lambda_call_operator_invoker<T>;
    }
};
```

This fails to compile on [all three of Clang, GCC, and MSVC,](https://godbolt.org/g/pLt3Df) which can certainly be surprising, since we were expecting reference collapsing to happen on the `T&&` argument.

However, **the standard doesn't support this.**

---

The important parts of the standard are [**[temp.deduct.funcaddr]**](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.funcaddr) (deducing template arguments taking the address of a function template) and [**[temp.deduct.conv]**](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.conv) (deducing conversion function template arguments). Critically, [**[temp.deduct.type]**](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#10) specifically mentions **[temp.deduct.funcaddr]**, but not **[temp.deduct.conv]**.

Some terms used in the standard:

- P is the return type of the conversion template, or the type of the function template
- A is the type we are "trying to convert to"

> Similarly, if P has a form that contains (T), then each parameter type P<sub>i</sub> of the respective parameter-type-list ([dcl.fct]) of P is compared with the corresponding parameter type A<sub>i</sub> of the corresponding parameter-type-list of A. *If P and A are function types that originated from deduction when taking the address of a function template ([temp.deduct.funcaddr]) or when deducing template arguments from a function declaration ([temp.deduct.decl]) and P<sub>i</sub> and A<sub>i</sub> are parameters of the top-level parameter-type-list of P and A, respectively, 
>   P<sub>i</sub> is adjusted if it is a forwarding reference ([temp.deduct.call]) and A<sub>i</sub> is an lvalue reference, in which case the type of P<sub>i</sub> is changed to be the template parameter type (i.e., `T&&` is changed to simply `T`).*

<sup>emphasis added</sup>

This specifically calls out taking the address of a function template, making forwarding references just work. There is no similar reference to conversion function templates.

Revisiting the example earlier, if we change `fn_type` to `void(*)(T)`, that is the same operation that is described here in the standard.

Comment: I think you are right w.r.t. the template deduction part. If we take the example from [expr.prim.lambda]/8 (replacing `T` with `T&&`) as appropriate) and keep boiling it down, template deduction will keep failing until the conversion operator is replaced with a member function. [Godbolt link.](https://godbolt.org/g/irm21L)

Comment: Grumble. Foiled again :<