# Get a pointer to a templated lambda operator () without captures

Tags: c++, c++20

Can anyone tell me a valid way to get a pointer to a templated lamda (without caputes) operator () ? Already tried two alternatives:

```
int main()
{
    static
    auto l = []<bool a, bool b>( unsigned c ) -> unsigned
    {
        return (unsigned)a + b + c;
    };
    using fn_t = unsigned (*)( unsigned );
    fn_t fnA = &l.operator ()<true, false>; // doesn't work
    fn_t fnB = &decltype(l)::operator ()<true, false>; // also doesn't work
}
```

clang(-cl) 12:

```
x.cpp(9,13): error: cannot create a non-constant pointer to member function
        fn_t fnA = &l.operator ()<true, false> ; // doesn't work
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
x.cpp(10,14): error: address of overloaded function 'operator()' does not match required type
      'unsigned int (unsigned int)'
        fn_t fnB = &decltype(l)::operator ()<true, false> ; // also doesn't work
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
x.cpp(4,11): note: candidate function template has different qualifiers (expected unqualified but found 'const')
        auto l = []<bool a, bool b>(unsigned c) -> unsigned
                 ^
```

MSVC 2019 latest update:

```
x.cpp(9): error C2276: '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression
x.cpp(10): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'fn_t'
x.cpp(10): note: None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type
```

Comment: please include compiler errors in the question. Different compilers and different flags can change errors substantially

Comment: Somewhat related: [Converting a forwarding lambda to a function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428022/converting-a-forwarding-lambda-to-a-function-pointer). That one is about template argument deduction and reference collapsing.

Answer (score 4):

The type of the address of lambda's `operator()` is a member function pointer, however, the definition of your `fn_t` is just a free function pointer. You should define your `fn_t` as:

```
using fn_t = unsigned int (decltype(l)::*)(unsigned int) const;
```

Then the following should work:

```
fn_t fnA = &decltype(l)::operator ()<true, false>;
```

Or, why not?

```
auto fnB = &decltype(l)::operator ()<true, false>;
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/n1qffh5zW)

Comment: I think goal of OP is to have a function pointer. That member function pointer is mostly useless...

Answer (score 3):

It is the lambda which can be converted to function pointer in some conditions (which are not there here), not its member `operator()`. And you cannot convert member pointer to function pointer.

One workaround is to use another lambda.

```
fn_t fn = [](unsigned c) { return decltype(l){}.operator()<true, false>(c); };
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PPPjv9qdW)

Comment: The MSVC compiler in the demo does fail compilation

Comment: @Dilettant: Used a version which doesn't support C++20 :/, fixed